# How do I accumulate results without using a mutable ArrayBuffer?

Tags: scala, immutability, mutable

The code at the end of this question replaces the zeros with possible numbers ranging from 1 to 9 once and non-repeating. For a given sequence of numbers, List(0, 0, 1, 5, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0), it will returns the following result. There are 720 permutations in total.

```
List(2, 3, 1, 5, 4, 6, 8, 7, 9)
List(2, 3, 1, 5, 4, 6, 8, 9, 7)
List(2, 3, 1, 5, 4, 7, 8, 6, 9)
List(2, 3, 1, 5, 4, 7, 8, 9, 6)
List(2, 3, 1, 5, 4, 9, 8, 6, 7)
List(2, 3, 1, 5, 4, 9, 8, 7, 6)
List(2, 3, 1, 5, 6, 4, 8, 7, 9)
...
```

My question is how do I convert my code to NOT using ArrayBuffer(`coll`) as my temporary storage and the final result is returned from the function(`search0`) instead?

Thanks

/lim/

```
import collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer

object ScratchPad extends App {
  def search(l : List[Int]) : ArrayBuffer[List[Int]] = {
    def search0(la : List[Int], pos : Int, occur : List[Int], coll : ArrayBuffer[List[Int]]) : Unit = {
    if (pos == l.length) {println(la); coll += la }
    val bal = (1 to 9) diff occur
    if (!bal.isEmpty) {
        la(pos) match {
        case 0 => bal map { x => search0(la.updated(pos, x), pos + 1, x :: occur, coll)}
        case n => if  (occur contains n) Nil else search0(la, pos + 1, n :: occur, coll)
        }
    }
    }

    val coll = ArrayBuffer[List[Int]]()

    search0(l, 0, Nil, coll)
    coll
  }

  println(search(List(0, 0, 1, 5, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0)).size)
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a shorter solution using immutable collection:

```
scala> def search(xs: Seq[Int])(implicit ys: Seq[Int] = (1 to 9).diff(xs)): Seq[Seq[Int]] = ys match {
     |   case Seq() => Seq(xs)
     |   case _ => ys.flatten(y => search(xs.updated(xs.indexOf(0), y))(ys.diff(Seq(y))))
     | }
search: (xs: Seq[Int])(implicit ys: Seq[Int])Seq[Seq[Int]]

scala> search(List(0, 0, 1, 5, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0)).size
res0: Int = 720

scala> search(List(0, 0, 1, 5, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0)) take 10 foreach println
List(2, 3, 1, 5, 4, 6, 8, 7, 9)
List(2, 3, 1, 5, 4, 6, 8, 9, 7)
List(2, 3, 1, 5, 4, 7, 8, 6, 9)
List(2, 3, 1, 5, 4, 7, 8, 9, 6)
List(2, 3, 1, 5, 4, 9, 8, 6, 7)
List(2, 3, 1, 5, 4, 9, 8, 7, 6)
List(2, 3, 1, 5, 6, 4, 8, 7, 9)
List(2, 3, 1, 5, 6, 4, 8, 9, 7)
List(2, 3, 1, 5, 6, 7, 8, 4, 9)
List(2, 3, 1, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 4)
```

An even more shorter solution:

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

def search(xs: Seq[Int], ys: Seq[Int] = 1 to 9): Seq[Seq[Int]] = ys.diff(xs) match {
  case Seq() => Seq(xs)
  case zs => zs.flatten(z => search(xs.updated(xs.indexOf(0),z),zs))
}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

search: (xs: Seq[Int], ys: Seq[Int])Seq[Seq[Int]]

scala> search(List(0, 0, 1, 5, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0)).size
res1: Int = 720

scala> search(List(0, 0, 1, 5, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0)) take 10 foreach println
List(2, 3, 1, 5, 4, 6, 8, 7, 9)
List(2, 3, 1, 5, 4, 6, 8, 9, 7)
List(2, 3, 1, 5, 4, 7, 8, 6, 9)
List(2, 3, 1, 5, 4, 7, 8, 9, 6)
List(2, 3, 1, 5, 4, 9, 8, 6, 7)
List(2, 3, 1, 5, 4, 9, 8, 7, 6)
List(2, 3, 1, 5, 6, 4, 8, 7, 9)
List(2, 3, 1, 5, 6, 4, 8, 9, 7)
List(2, 3, 1, 5, 6, 7, 8, 4, 9)
List(2, 3, 1, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 4)
```

Comment: Will it make a difference for using zs.flatMap instead of zs.flatten in this case and in general? I tested and the results are the same.

Comment: There is a tiny issue here that can be easily solved with using a pre condition guard to reject a list with duplicate elements. Otherwise it will return 720 for List(1, 0, 1, 5, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0) which is wrong. The other way is built the checks inside i.e. 

case zs => zs.flatten(z => {val pos = xs.indexOf(0); if (pos < 0) Nil else search(xs.updated(pos, z),zs)})

Answer (score 0):

Naive refactoring of your code using only immutable data structures:

```
object ScratchPad extends App {
    def search(l: List[Int]): List[List[Int]] = {
        def search0(la: List[Int], pos: Int, occur: List[Int]): List[List[Int]] =
            if (pos == l.length)
                List(la)
            else {
                val bal = (1 to 9) diff occur
                if (pos < l.length && !bal.isEmpty)
                    la(pos) match {
                        case 0 => bal.toList flatMap {x => search0(la.updated(pos, x), pos + 1, x :: occur)}
                        case n => if (occur contains n) List.empty[List[Int]] else search0(la, pos + 1, n :: occur)
                    }
                else
                    List.empty[List[Int]]
            }

        search0(l, 0, Nil)
    }

    val result = search(List(0, 0, 1, 5, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0))
    result foreach println
    println(result.size)
}
```

Comment: Thanks. the similarity to my solution  helped me to see my mistakes. however, Eastsun has a solution that I was waiting for.